# how to control cell redefinition

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have three sections, the first one stores the user's information , the second one contains the field for adding posts, and the third one is posts.
And when scrolling, I start to load the section with the addition of posts and the user information section in the posts section
[image]
[image]

This is my code
UIViewController extension UITableViewDataSource :

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        presenter?.numberOfSections() ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let section = UserPageTypeSection(rawValue: section) else { return 0 }
        return presenter?.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section) ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let section = UserPageTypeSection(rawValue: indexPath.section),
              let userInfo = presenter?.cellForRowAt(section: section, indexRow: indexPath.row)
              else { return UITableViewCell() }
        switch userInfo.type {
        case .userInfo:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProfileInfoTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ProfileInfoTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.userInformation(userData: userInfo.data?[indexPath.row] as? UserProfile)
            return cell
            
        case .userAddPost:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProfileInfoTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ProfileInfoTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.addPostUser()
            return cell
        case .userPost:
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ProfileInfoTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ProfileInfoTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.post(text: "POST")
            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This is not C. This is Swift?

Comment: How to make sure that there are no duplicate cells in other sections where they should not have been

Comment: I don't understand the whole thing: in `cellForRow`, why do you have a switch and then dequeue the same cell type all the way? And what are the "duplicate cells in other sections"? Depending on the section, _you_ are filling the cells with content, so _you_ are responsible for the correct data.